# React testing library toHaveStyle for css sheet (ButtonFace)

Tags: css, react-testing-library

I have styles applied to a button via a css sheet. When the app starts the button has only a .Button class. When the button is clicked an extra `.clicked` class is added, which then modifies the styling for the button. The button text also changes from 'button' to 'button clicked'.

I would like RTL to look for these styling changes (which are plainly visible when running the app).

button.css:

```
.Button {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.clicked {
    transform: scale(8.0);
    background-color: red;
}
```

test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { cleanup, render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import App from './App';


describe('clicking on the button', () => {

  afterAll(cleanup);

  let upDatedButton: HTMLElement;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const { getByText, findByText } = render(<App />);
    const button = getByText('button');

    fireEvent(
      button,
      new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      })
    )

    upDatedButton = await findByText('button clicked');
  });

  // the button has been click: it's text is now different
  it('button text changes', async () => {
    expect(upDatedButton).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(upDatedButton).toBeInstanceOf(HTMLButtonElement);
  });

  it('style changes after click', async () => {
    expect(upDatedButton).toHaveClass('Button clicked');  //clicked class is picked up

    // fails here: only style is background-color: ButtonFace
    expect(upDatedButton).toHaveStyle(`
      transform: scale(8.0);
      background-color: red;
    `);
  });

});
```

`toHaveStyle()` is not picking up these new styles but rather something completely different, a background color of "ButtonFace":

> ```
> expect(element).toHaveStyle()
>
> - Expected
>
> - background-color: red;
> - transform: scale(8.0);
> + background-color: ButtonFace;
> ```

How do I test for the styles that the user should be seeing? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The style never got applied, even though the class did. It is not possible as JSDOM limitations [cannot guarantee the stylesheet being loaded in](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/295#issuecomment-705850145).

Additional info: ButtonFace is the default value for button, a CSS2 color name corresponding to HEX value: `#F0F0F0` http://www.iangraham.org/books/xhtml1/appd/update-23feb2000.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue the quick solution is to make inline style.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).